# How to display full name from combobox to textbox separated by space

Tags: c#, string, join, combobox, textbox

I have connection with local database. I wanted full name from (in this case) `combobox4` to textbox `textbox`. It displays this value but without separation with space. For example from `combobox4` "S BOX" in `textbox` is only "S". I tried with `textBox4.Text = string.Join(" ", parts[1]);` but i couldn't work. I share my code:
Insertstatus.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace KontrolaBazaDanych
{
    public partial class InsertStatus : Form
    {
        string Zlecenie_wykonane;
        string Zlecenie_rozpoczete;
        MySqlConnection connection;
        MySqlCommand command;
        MySqlDataReader dr;
        Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        public InsertStatus()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=");
                string InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO projekt1.status_zl(ID_ZLECENIA, ID_PRACOWNIKA, ID_MODULU, ID_PROJEKTU, ILOSC_PRODUKTOW, DATA_ROZPOCZECIA, DATA_ZAKONCZENIA, ZLECENIE_WYKONANE, ZLECENIE_ROZPOCZETE) VALUES('" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','"+ textBox10.Text +"','" + numericUpDown4.Value.ToString() + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss") + "','" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss") + "','" + Zlecenie_wykonane + "','" + Zlecenie_rozpoczete + "')";
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(InsertQuery, connection);

                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Dane są dodane.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Błąd.");
                }

                frm1.loaddata4();

                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox2.Clear();
                textBox3.Clear();
                textBox4.Clear();
                textBox5.Clear();
                textBox6.Clear();
                textBox7.Clear();
                textBox8.Clear();
                textBox9.Clear();

                numericUpDown4.Value = 0;

                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
                dateTimePicker2.Value = DateTime.Now;

                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                checkBox2.Checked = false;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zlecenie_wykonane = "1";
            Zlecenie_rozpoczete = "0";
        }

        private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Zlecenie_wykonane = "0";
            Zlecenie_rozpoczete = "1";
        }

        private void InsertStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";

            connection.Open();
            string selectQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM projekt1.pracownicy";
            MySqlCommand command2 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery2, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader2.GetString("ID_PRACOWNIKA") + " " + reader2.GetString("IMIE") + " " + reader2.GetString("NAZWISKO"));
            }
            connection.Close();

            connection.Open();
            string selectQuery3 = "SELECT * FROM projekt1.moduly";
            MySqlCommand command3 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery3, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader3 = command3.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader3.Read())
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(reader3.GetString("NAZWA"));
            }
            connection.Close();

            connection.Open();
            string selectQuery4 = "SELECT * FROM projekt1.zlecenia";
            MySqlCommand command4 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery4, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader4 = command4.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader4.Read())
            {
                comboBox3.Items.Add(reader4.GetString("NUMER_ZLECENIA"));
            }
            connection.Close();

            connection.Open();
            string selectQuery5 = "SELECT * FROM projekt1.projekty";
            MySqlCommand command5 = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery5, connection);
            MySqlDataReader reader5 = command5.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader5.Read())
            {
                comboBox4.Items.Add(reader5.GetString("ID") + " " + reader5.GetString("NAZWA_PROJEKTU"));
            }
            connection.Close();
            textBox1.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox8.Enabled = false;
            textBox9.Enabled = false;
            textBox10.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM projekt1.moduly WHERE NAZWA='"+ comboBox2.Text +"'", connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MySqlDataReader dr;
            dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string nazwa = (string)dr["NAZWA"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = nazwa;

                string id_modulu = (string)dr["ID_MODULU"].ToString();
                textBox8.Text = id_modulu;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM projekt1.zlecenia WHERE NUMER_ZLECENIA='" + comboBox3.Text+"'", connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string opis = (string)dr["OPIS_ZLECENIA"].ToString();
                textBox5.Text = opis;

                string numer = (string)dr["NUMER_ZLECENIA"].ToString();
                textBox6.Text = numer;

                string status_zl = (string)dr["ID_ZLECENIA"].ToString();
                textBox7.Text = status_zl;
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string[] parts = comboBox1.Items[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split(' ');
                textBox9.Text = parts[0];
                textBox1.Text = parts[1];
                textBox2.Text = parts[2];
            }
        }

        private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox4.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string[] parts = comboBox4.Items[comboBox4.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split(' ');

                    textBox10.Text = parts[0];
                    textBox4.Text = string.Join(" ", parts[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find any solution which may be effective. It's about `string.Join` construction or should create public class? Has someone idea how to solve it or explain by example code? Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i've got that solution which i can do that and it's for now solved:

```
   private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             if (comboBox4.SelectedIndex != -1)
             {
                string[] parts = comboBox4.Items[comboBox4.SelectedIndex].ToString().Split(' ');
                textBox10.Text = parts[0];
                textBox4.Text = comboBox4.Text.Remove(0,2).Trim();

             }
```